# retaining values across screen sin JSF2.0

Tags: session, jsf-2

I am working on JSF2.0 project where I need to get value in backing bean from previous screen I  have explained it below

my first screen

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="LocationID" />
        <h:inputText value="#{getDetails.locationID}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Add OS" action="#{getDetails.addOSDetails}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
 </html>
```

My backing bean when the commandButton is invoked

```
@ManagedBean(name="getDetails")
@RequestScoped
public class GetDetailsBean {

private String locationID;

public String getLocationID() {
    return locationID;
}

public void setLocationID(String locationID) {
    this.locationID = locationID;
}   

public String addOSDetails(){
    return "/app_pages/addOS";
}

}
```

My second screen which is addOS is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Enter Value" />
        <h:inputText value="#{addOS.addValue}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Add OS" action="#{addOS.save}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
 </html>
```

I want the LocationID entered in the first screen to be available in this backing bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="addOS")
@RequestScoped
public class AddOS {

private String addValue;

public String getAddValue() {
    return addValue;
}

public void setAddValue(String addValue) {
    this.addValue = addValue;
}

public String save(){
    return "app_pages/success";
}
```

}

I donot want values to be set in session.Can  be used.

Thoughts and help please

Thanks.

Comment: if you want an attribute to be used in more than 1 view, then it should be stored in a SessionScope

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend to do **a forward**, as you do in your question, the submitted on the first page data is already there when the second page is rendered: remember, the forward is done within the same HTTP request. So, what you ultimately need is to keep the value for a subsequesnt POST request. You can do it, for example, by storing the information is a hidden field on the second page:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{getDetails.locationID}" />
```

And that's basically it.

If you intend to do **a redirect**, thus by appending `?faces-redirect=true` to a navigation case outcome, you need to store that information in EL flash to be able to retrieve it in the recepient page: there are two requests to be done. So, change your first bean's action method to the following:

```
public String action() {
    ...
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("locationID", locationID);
    return "result?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This way on the recepient page it will be available in flash map, thus by

```
#{flash.locationID}
```

in EL scope and

```
(String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getFlash().get("locationID");
```

in Java code.